# If Bender can survive as a ghost, why the concern for the lack of backup units?

Tags: technology, futurama

In the Futurama episode, *Lethal Inspection*, it's revealed that Bender has a defect where he lacks the ability to upload himself to backup bodies in the case of his body being destroyed.  But in *Ghost in the Machines*, Bender dies and becomes a ghost.  He finds he can possess electrical objects while he's a ghost.  So why the concern over the lack of backup units, if he's still basically immortal?

Comment: Does Futurama does really count as Sci Fi? Its a cartoon comedy set in a future where Nixons head in a jar is president...

Comment: Are you arguing that Nixon's head in a jar in the future is science-fact?

Comment: It is more parody of sci fi than actual sci fi.  Besides you dont think they really have space ships in area 51 do you?  No thats where our presidents are all chryogenically preserved until we can cut off their heads and reelect them president.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well *Lethal Inspection* was aired first, so chronologically thinking, Bender didn't know he could become a ghost (it aired one year before *Ghost in the Machines*).  If he had known then it probably wouldn't have been a problem.

[*Lethal Inspection*](http://theinfosphere.org/Lethal_Inspection)
[*Ghost in the Machines*](http://theinfosphere.org/Ghost_in_the_Machines)

Answer (score 2):

In 'The Ghost in the Machines', the Robot Devil says that Bender is **only a ghost because he committed suicide, thus being stuck in robot limbo.**

If he were to die normally it can be assumed that instead of ending up as a ghost in robot limbo he would end up in Robot Heaven or Robot Hell (he goes to both in that episode).

Answer (score 1):

Well, he doesn't really survive as a ghost; he more or less is in limbo as a ghost.